# linq predicate remove objects from collection issue

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to figure out why my delegate function does not work, any help would be appreciated, this is probably a small issue but I have been working on it for a while and connot figure it out, my code:

```
//remove all matching people from this list
public void RemovePeopleFromLookup(Predicate<PeopleDTO> _people)
{
   //Lookup is an internal readonly ICollection of PeopleDTO
   Lookup.RemoveAll(_people);
}
```

//call the method as below:
//data is a collection of PeopleDTO

```
mylookupobj.RemovePeopleFromLookup(x => data.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name && x.Type == FieldElement.Strange));
```

For some reason all people get removed from this lookup, this is not correct, I only want to remove the people who are

1. Strange
2. who **DONOT** exist in the **data** collection

EDIT:

The **data collection** can be an object of **different types** -> strange, noisy etc...
The **mylookupobj.Lookup** data collection is similar to the data collection and contain contain **multiple types** hence why I wrote my query that way

EDIT2: I missed out this information which may be very important...

```
public class PersonDTO
{
//Name
//Type
//Age
//Desc
}
```

Inside the mylookupobj.Lookup - all the properties contain data, however inside the data collection only the Name + Type is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler and more efficient predicate would be:

```
x => (x.Type == FieldElement.Strange) && data.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name)
```

But I admit I don't see a principal problem with either.

Edit: seems 1 of the conditions has to be inverted.

```
x => (x.Type == FieldElement.Strange) && ! data.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name)
```

Comment: Sorry... I just realised my question said to remove all those that exist in the data collection, it was meant to be... Remove all objects that from mylookupobj.Lookup that do not exist in the data collection, could you update your answer?

Comment: I thikn I understand where I went wrong, the ! was the thing I totally messed up on, I greatly appreciate your help. :p

Answer (score 1):

The call to Any is the problem. Essentially it's running through the collection multiple times. i.e. if any of the objects in the collection matches the condition, remove the item. Try this:

```
mylookupobj.RemoveFieldFromLookup(y => y.Name == x.Name && x.Type == FieldElement.Strange);
```

Comment: I need to refer to data- I have amended to make the *data* bold

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
mylookupobj.RemovePeopleFromLookup(x => data.Contains(y => y.Name == x.Name) 
     && x.Type == FieldElement.Strange);
```

Comment: Is this a lambda not a predicate?

Comment: It looks like a fine predicate-lambda